# Create Pie Charts from JSON with multiple column

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to create a pie chart (using D3.js) from my JSON data. I know it is possible to create it from multiple rows and with only two columns. For example, if JSON data is something like this

```
    [{"name":"Kamran","count":"4"},{"name":"Krishana","count":"6"}]
```

I found this example for data above https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/sv6j8nh4/

But my data contains a single row with multiple columns for example

```
    [{"name":"Task1","Agree":"4","Disagree":"22","Inbetween":"4"}]
```

How can I create a pie chart with this type of data?

Comment: You need to reformat that json to be in a group per response.

Comment: That is not D3, that is Canvas.js. If you want help regarding D3, please share the code that creates the pie chart with the original data using D3, then we can help you to convert your current data structure to one that works... otherwise, you are asking us to *write the whole datavoz code*, which of course is off-topic.

Comment: can you please check it here ? I hope you'll get what you wanted to do.

http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html

Answer (score 0):

You can render pie chart from the JSON that you have shared by [iterating through the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Find the working code below.

```js
var dataPoints = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Pie chart from JSON data"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "pie",
    toolTipContent: "{indexLabel}: {y}",
    dataPoints: dataPoints
  }]
});

function addData(data) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var key in data[i]){
      if(!isNaN(data[i][key])){
        dataPoints.push({indexLabel: key, y: Number(data[i][key])});
      }
    }
  }
  chart.render();
}

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dxzog", addData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A pie chart can have one dimension column and one measure column. You are probably trying to create a pie chart from two dimension columns (name and agreement). You can't do that in one pie chart. You will need to pre-process your JSON and create something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Task1",
    "agreements": [
      {
        "name": "Agree",
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Disagree",
        "count": 22
      },
      {
        "name": "InBetween",
        "count": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Task2",
    "agreements": [
      {
        "name": "Agree",
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Disagree",
        "count": 22
      },
      {
        "name": "InBetween",
        "count": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then create one pie chart of each task or show the chart for one task at a time.